# (Sequelize+Postgres+NodeJS) Inster FK (userID) from another table

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm using Sequelize connected to PostgreSQL and as I want to use sync function I would like to prepare valid models to create tables on every environment.

**EDIT:**

Wallet:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(db, DataTypes) {
  var Wallet = db.define('Wallet', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    money: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0
    }
    createdAt: DataTypes.DATE,
    updatedAt: DataTypes.DATE
  }, {
    tableName: 'wallet',
    classMethods:{
      associate : function( models ) {
        Wallet.belongsTo( models.User,{ foreignKey : 'id_user'});
      }
    }

  });

  return Wallet;
};
```

User:

```
'use strict';
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var crypto = require('crypto');
var moment = require('moment');
var models = require('./');


var afterCreateHook = function(user, options, fn) {
  models.Wallet.build({id_user: user.id}).save();
  fn(null, user);
};

module.exports = function(db, DataTypes) {
  var User = db.define('User', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false,
      isEmail: true
    },
    login: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true,
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'pl_users',
    instanceMethods: instanceMethods,
    classMethods: {
      associate : function( models ) {
        User.hasOne( models.Wallet);
      }

    },
    hooks: {
      afterCreate: afterCreateHook
    }
  });

  return User;
};
```

Why

```
models.Wallet.build({id_user: user.id}).save();
```

is not working? Account is creating and then I want to create wallet with specific user_id. I don't have even an error...

Help please!

Answer (score 0):

You should check [relations](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/.) from sequelize docs

In your case youu need to define:

```
Wallet.belongsTo(User,{foreignKey: 'id_user'});
```

This will add id_user to Wallet model , so you dont need to specify id_user attribute in your WalletModel.

If you are using sequelize import function , you should add the relation in "associate" class method like this:

```
module.exports = function(db, DataTypes) {
  var Wallet = db.define('Wallet', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    pin: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0
    },
    money: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      defaultValue: 0
    },
    createdAt: DataTypes.DATE,
    updatedAt: DataTypes.DATE
  }, {
    tableName: 'Wallet',
    classMethods:{
           associate : function( models ) {
                Wallet.belongsTo( models.User,{ foreignKey : 'id_user'});
            }
    }
  });
```

Comment: if you need to create a new wallet to a existing user , you could use user.createWallet({ }).

Comment: can you be more specific? Its great idea but idk where to put that...

now its working with:
`var afterCreateHook = function(user, options, fn) {
  this.associations.Wallet.target.create({ id_user: user.id })
      .then(function(otherModel) {
        fn(null, user);
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        return;
      });
};`

Comment: I need more information , if you have a instance of User called user , it have association methods , one of them is createWallet , because user have a association with wallet , so you can do  : user.createWallet({pin:123456,money:"PEN"}).then(..).catch(..)